# Problem during distribute file .ipa to Apple store: __CFCopyServerVersionDictionary

Tags: gluon-mobile, darwin, graalvm

I create the ipa file with graalVM and client-maven-plugin. When I try to distribute into the apple Store I have this error.

```
ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public symbols in <NAME APP> : __CFCopyServerVersionDictionary, __CFCopySystemVersionDictionary. If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions.
```

How I can solve?

Comment: What GraalVM version are you using? Did you follow https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples#building-and-running-the-samples-on-ios?

Comment: I check my graallVM and I follow the guide. Now when I invoce mvn client:link I receive thie error:


ang.IllegalArgumentException: Linking failed, since there is no objectfile named <packagename>.<main_class_lowercase>.o under /<path_my_dir>/target/client/arm64-ios/gvm
    at com.gluonhq.substrate.target.AbstractTargetConfiguration.lambda$link$0 (AbstractTargetConfiguration.java:210)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow (Optional.java:408)
    at com.gluonhq.substrate.target.AbstractTargetConfiguration.link (208)
......

Comment: If you have a new GraalVM version, do `mvn clean client:build` and see if it works. Else, you will need to post more details...

Comment: It's ok. I reinstalled everything and now I publish the IPA in the Apple store. Thank you